# adding a word to column of dataframe depending on other column

Tags: python, pandas

I have scrapped tweets, already with the sentiment (0-negative,1-positive), the sentiments were based on emojis, but after that emojis were deleted from scrapped tweets.

For the better model, I want to add to every one of the tweets word based on the sentiment (positive -> "*smile*", negative -> "*cry*").

How to do that?
The sentiment are in *sentiment_label* column and the tweets are in *tweet_text* column.